# Defining y value within annotate as value in column after selectInput

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, annotate, selectinput

I have a plot for each category that can be selected via selectInput. In each plot, there is a horizontal line that indicates the control mean. The height of this line changes for each category. The height is taken from the column called "Control" - the value in that column changes for each category. That all works fine.

However, I want to add text just above this line that says "Control Mean". When I try to do that I get an error saying that Control cannot be found. Can please someone explain why this is happening and how to resolve it?

```
    #Plot 
cbPalette <- c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73") #color-blind friendly palette or "#CC79A7"?

fun_select_cat <- function(table, cat) {
  table %>% 
    filter(variable == cat)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(selectInput('cat','Select Category', c('Number of Enterprises','Assets','Costs','Net Revenues','Revenues'))),
    mainPanel(plotOutput('plot_overall'))
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot_overall <- renderPlot({
    fun_select_cat(table_2, input$cat) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = Treatment, y = new_est, fill = Treatment)) +
      geom_col() + scale_fill_manual(values = cbPalette) +
      guides(fill = FALSE) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = label_comma(), expand = c(0,0)) +
      theme_classic() +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size=14,face="bold"),
            axis.text=element_text(size=12)) +
      geom_hline(aes(yintercept = Control), linetype='dashed', col = '#CC79A7', size = 1.5) +
       annotate("text", x = 3.53, y = 1.075*Control, 
           label = "Control\nmean",
           colour = "#CC79A7",
           fontface =2) +
            if(input$cat %in% c("Number of Enterprises", "Assets")
      ) {labs(title= input$cat, x = NULL, y = NULL)
      } else{labs(title = paste(input$cat, "(USD) for the last 30 days", sep =" "), x = NULL, y = NULL)}
     
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

dput(table_2)

```
structure(list(Treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Long Term", 
"Short Term", "Lump Sum"), class = "factor"), variable = c("Number of Enterprises", 
"Assets", "Costs", "Net Revenues", "Revenues", "Number of Enterprises", 
"Assets", "Costs", "Net Revenues", "Revenues", "Number of Enterprises", 
"Assets", "Costs", "Net Revenues", "Revenues"), Control = c(73.23, 
100036.59, 92636.84, 54533.59, 150207.24, 73.23, 100036.59, 92636.84, 
54533.59, 150207.24, 73.23, 100036.59, 92636.84, 54533.59, 150207.24
), Estimate = c(9.93, 36050.66, 32055.29, 28226.05, 61379.4, 
14.67, 29404.54, 71903.23, 35576.39, 107746.75, 3.39, 16441.81, 
8497.42, 14824.71, 23177.47), SE = c(3.96, 12589.11, 16478.13, 
12334.27, 24346.05, 3.92, 10977.68, 24360.84, 13382.81, 34895.03, 
3.57, 10029.27, 10462.44, 8143.69, 16080.92), Sig = c("∗∗", 
"∗∗∗", "∗", "∗∗", "∗∗", "∗∗∗", "∗∗∗", 
"∗∗∗", "∗∗∗", "∗∗∗", NA, NA, NA, "∗", NA), 
    new_est = c(83.16, 136087.25, 124692.13, 82759.64, 211586.64, 
    87.9, 129441.13, 164540.07, 90109.98, 257953.99, 76.62, 116478.4, 
    101134.26, 69358.3, 173384.71), lower = c(75.3984, 111412.5944, 
    92394.9952, 58584.4708, 163868.382, 80.2168, 107924.8772, 
    116792.8236, 63879.6724, 189559.7312, 69.6228, 96821.0308, 
    80627.8776, 53396.6676, 141866.1068), higher = c(90.9216, 
    160761.9056, 156989.2648, 106934.8092, 259304.898, 95.5832, 
    150957.3828, 212287.3164, 116340.2876, 326348.2488, 83.6172, 
    136135.7692, 121640.6424, 85319.9324, 204903.3132)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), groups = structure(list(
    variable = c("Assets", "Costs", "Net Revenues", "Number of Enterprises", 
    "Revenues"), .rows = structure(list(c(2L, 7L, 12L), c(3L, 
    8L, 13L), c(4L, 9L, 14L), c(1L, 6L, 11L), c(5L, 10L, 15L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: `annotate` doesn't have access to your data, access to data within layers is given by the `aes` function. Easies way would be to save the value for `Control` in a new object within the `renderPlot` function, like `control_y = fun_select_cat(table_2, input$cat) |> pull(Control) |> unique() `, and then use that inside `annotate` instead of `Control`